# Spark SQL (coorelated subQuery) creates a BroadcastNestedLoopJoin and the job runs very slow

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

**What am I trying to do**

I have 3 tables which are being joined to create a desired output.

Table 1 (800K records) : This is a partitioned hive external table by date (parquet file structure ). The schema is deeply nested. Following is a portion of the schema

```
root
  | - uuid
  | - data
         | - k1 - string
         | - k2 - string
         | - ...
  | ….
  | - dt - string (partition column)
```

Table 2 (0.5 million records) /Table 3 (31K records) : metadata tables

```
root
  | - insert_date
  | - k_sub
  | - action_date
  | ….
```

SQL being executed (Generated by a internal library)

```
SELECT input_file_name() as filename, uuid, data.k1, data.k2, dt
FROM table_1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table_2 WHERE (k_sub = data.k1) AND dt > action_date)
  AND EXISTS(
        SELECT 1 FROM table_3 WHERE (k_sub = data.k1) AND (dt < action_date OR dt < DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), -1460))
```

Spark settings

```
Num of executors = 50
Executor memory = 10g
Driver memory = 10g
```

The query runs very slow runs for 1.1 hrs and fails. Looking into the sparkUI (SQL table).

I increased the num of executors to 100 and the job completed but I'm not confident. The plan looks like this

[image]

Based on my research, `BroadcastNestedLoopJoin` is not good to have. As it is SQL, I tried adding /* +BroadcastJoin */ hint but still did not help. Anyone has thoughts of how I could approach this problem and improve the performance?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with the non-equi join (as mentioned by @M_S). I ended up rewriting the sql query without using `exists`  and `not exists`. The new query was like

```
SELECT DISTINCT uuid, data, dt FROM 
   (SELECT uuid, data, dt
      FROM table_1
    MINUS
    SELECT uuid, data, dt
      FROM table_1 
      INNER JOIN table_2 ON (k_sub = data.k1)
      WHERE dt > action_date))
INNER JOIN table_3 ON (k_sub = data.k1)
WHERE dt < action_date 
UNION
 SELECT uuid, data, dt FROM 
   (SELECT uuid, data, dt
      FROM table_1
    MINUS
    SELECT uuid, data, dt
      FROM table_1 
      INNER JOIN table_2 ON (k_sub = data.k1)
      WHERE dt > action_date))
WHERE dt < DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), -1460)
```

The output of the above query was similar to the previous query but following were the spark configs

```
Num of executors = 50
Executor memory = 10g
Driver memory = 10g
```

It took

```
|table_1 | table_2 | table_3 | timetaken|
+--------+---------+---------+----------|
|800K    | 500K    |  31K    | 2.3 mins |
+--------+---------+---------+----------|
|195M    | 500K    |  31K    |  14 mins |
+--------+---------+---------+----------|
```

The query plan had multiple stages but had broadcastJoins, sortMergeJoins but did not create any broadcastNestedLoopJoin. It worked for my use case.

Thanks to all who shared suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem before, i had a table with billion records and 3 more (with hundred thousand rows) tables to enrich my table. I was combining them and doing aggregation. it was accelerated when I added the following configurations. but now I don't remember exactly which config I accelerated it with. It's been a long time since. I hope it works for you...

I have given these additionally when creating spark session ;

```
.config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict") \
.config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true") \
.config("hive.metastore.try.direct.sql", "true") \
.config("hive.merge.smallfiles.avgsize", "40000000") \
.config("hive.merge.size.per.task", "209715200") \
.config("hive.exec.parallel", "true") \
.config("spark.debug.maxToStringFields", "5000") \
.config("spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead","22g") \
.config("dfs.blocksize", "268435456") \
.config("spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max", "2000m") \
.config("spark.sql.adaptive.enabled", "true") \
.config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions","3200") \
.config("spark.default.parallelism","3200") \
```

After creating the session, I set the following configurations. Especially after adding **autoBroadcastJoinThreshold** below i saw it speed up;

```
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext

c = HiveContext(spark)
c.setConf('spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec', 'gzip')
c.setConf('spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold', 1000 * 1024 * 1024)
c.setConf('spark.sql.broadcastTimeout', '36000')
c.setConf("spark.sql.adaptive.skewJoin.enabled","true")
```

Comment: @venganzombie Than you for your reply. Unfortunately, none of the above made a change. some of the properties are not supported in 2.4.3 like spark.sql.adaptive.*.

Answer (score 0):

> Based on my research, BroadcastNestedLoopJoin is not good to have. As
> it is SQL, I tried adding /* +BroadcastJoin */ hint but still did not
> help. Anyone has thoughts of how I could approach this problem and
> improve the performance?

Looks like those not exists are translated into non-equi join (because they are using checking range on the condition) and in this case Spark cannot use hash join or sort-merge join. Thats also the reason why your broadcast hint is not forcing spark to use broadcastHashJoin (its only for equi join)

You can find more details in this comment in source code [Spark source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/SparkStrategies.scala#L209)

```
// If it is an equi-join, we first look at the join hints w.r.t. the following order:
      //   1. broadcast hint: pick broadcast hash join if the join type is supported. If both sides
      //      have the broadcast hints, choose the smaller side (based on stats) to broadcast.
      //   2. sort merge hint: pick sort merge join if join keys are sortable.
      //   3. shuffle hash hint: We pick shuffle hash join if the join type is supported. If both
      //      sides have the shuffle hash hints, choose the smaller side (based on stats) as the
      //      build side.
      //   4. shuffle replicate NL hint: pick cartesian product if join type is inner like.
      //
      // If there is no hint or the hints are not applicable, we follow these rules one by one:
      //   1. Pick broadcast hash join if one side is small enough to broadcast, and the join type
      //      is supported. If both sides are small, choose the smaller side (based on stats)
      //      to broadcast.
      //   2. Pick shuffle hash join if one side is small enough to build local hash map, and is
      //      much smaller than the other side, and `spark.sql.join.preferSortMergeJoin` is false.
      //   3. Pick sort merge join if the join keys are sortable.
      //   4. Pick cartesian product if join type is inner like.
      //   5. Pick broadcast nested loop join as the final solution. It may OOM but we don't have
      //      other choice.
```

If you cant change your condition i am afraid that you can only try to adjust your resources to make it stable and live with it